# How to send key with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I created a script with selenium to get given **GST NUMBER** information. I completed that program and it's giving me required details on output without any problem.

Now I do not want to interact it with chrome browser anymore so I'm trying to do this with BeautilfulSoup.

BeautifulSoup is new for me so I have not much idea to find element and I searched a lot about how to send keys with BeautifulSoup but I'm not getting it.

Now my script is stuck here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request as urllib2

quote_page = 'https://my.gstzen.in/p/search-taxpayer'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Now even if I manage to find the gst input element then I'm wondering how do I send keys to it? like the 15 digit gst number with sending enter button code or clicking on "Search GST Details".

If possible, then let me know the solution so I can start my research on it.

Actually, I need to do complete this tonight.

Plus, Here is my script which do the same thing with selenium easily and I want to do the same thing with BeautilfulSoup because I do not want chrome to be run every time while checking the GST and BeautilfulSoup seems interesting.

```
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import requests
#import pyvirtualdisplay            
#from pyvirtualdisplay import display

#display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
#display.start()


browser = webdriver.Chrome('E:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.set_window_position(-10000,0)
browser.get('https://my.gstzen.in/p/search-taxpayer/')


with open ('product.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        name, phone = row
        time.sleep(1)
        gst = browser.find_element_by_name('gstin')
        gst.click()
        gst.send_keys(name)
        time.sleep(1)
        Details = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '                Search GSTIN Details')]")
        Details.click()
        info = browser.find_element_by_class_name('col-sm-4')
        print(info.text)
        info2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')
        print(info2.text)
        input('Press Enter to quit')
        browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is a library for parsing and formatting, not interacting with web pages. For the latter, if that page requires JavaScript to work, you're stuck using a headless browser.

If it doesn't, you have at least two options:

1. Watch the Network tab in your browser's developer tools and see if you can recreate the request for the page you want using `requests` or `urllib2`
2. Use [`mechanize`](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is built specifically to work with forms on sites that don't depend on JavaScript

`mechanize` is a little more work if there's no CSRF token or similar mechanism (though, again, it'll fail if JavaScript is required) and a little less work if there is.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this. I'm going to try and see if it works.

Comment: You're welcome. Both options are things I've done myself recently while automating tasks at work, so they're definitely viable; hopefully at least one of them works for your target site.

Comment: Awesome. Again thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. Have a good day!